# Здравствуйте, что это предложение значит?

Tags: грамматика

Умней ли такой красавчик или красавица, чем другие ребята, добрее или способней?

Hello, I'm confused with the word умней, imperative of умнеть.

How do you translate this sentence?

Comment: 'Умней' is a colloquial version of the 'умнЕЕ' :)) (умней=умнЕЕ; способнЕЙ=способнЕЕ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately your confusion is caused by the coincidence of two forms. 
The first is (in your version ) an imperative of the verb "умнеть" – умней, and the second is (in reality) the comparative from the adjective "умный" – умнее, or умней

> Умней ли такой красавчик или красавица, чем другие ребята, добрее или способней? Is such a handsome boy or a beautiful girl **cleverer**, kinder, or more talented than other guys?

Answer (score 3):

Translatable as:
Is this he-beauty or she-beauty *more clever* ["умней"] than the other guys, or more kind or more gifted?